# file_get_contents() not working to same server

Tags: php, apache

I can't get content from same server domains with `file_get_contents()`.

Ex. my domain name is mydomain.com

- From this server when i have `file_get_contents('http://mydomain.com')` i got error Message:

  > file_get_contents(): failed to open stream: Connection timed out
- If I have `file_get_contents('http://google.com')` it's working
- If I add this php script `file_get_contents('http://mydomain.com')` to other server then its working. But with current server its not.

My server:

```
Ubuntu 12.04
Apache 2.4.9
PHP 5.5.10

allow_url_fopen = on
```

before `apt-get upgrade` everything worked

Comment: What does PHP's error reporting return?

Comment: isn't it like running a forever loop...fetching the same page from a particular page with file_get_contents()

Comment: Yes it's looks like this, but link which i used in file_get_contents()  when i paste in browser works fine

Comment: You clearly know what you upgraded, but we don't.  Only you can solve this problem.  Have you checked the obvious?  Your server is running?

Comment: Yes sure checked, server running, this function working with other domains just not this which is inside this server

Answer (score -1):

You should write this

```
$file = file_get_contents('YOUR FILE LOCATION (e.g. /rss.txt)', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
```

this work for me.

Answer (score -1):

I found where was problem:

was missed

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:72 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:72 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:114067 (114.0 KB)  TX bytes:114067 (114.0 KB)
```

from $ ifconfig

Comment: Would be nice to know what the problem was exactly as I face the same issue.

Comment: Dude! This is seriously not cool to post that you have found what's wrong, but not elaborate on the details when others clearly might benefit from what you found. Why don't you do us a solid and provide that?