# PHP 5.4 - file_get_contents not working when requesting urls on same server

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm unable to get content from same server domain for example the following returns empty:

```
file_get_contents('http://www.myexamplesite.com')
```

If I have `file_get_contents('http://google.com')` or any other external url it seems to work fine.

php.ini has `allow_url_fopen = on`

Already looked at the following post [file_get_contents() not working to same server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974330/file-get-contents-not-working-to-same-server) but OP hasn't provided a solution.

Any ideas - I'm suspecting it's an ip resolution problem?

Comment: Perhaps try cURL?

Comment: @Utkanos tried curl and that doesn't work for url's on same server but works for external urls

Comment: Turned on error reporting/display? Nothing in the error logs? Does your browser console show any errors?

Comment: are you using http/https in address correctly?

Comment: @maxpovver i've tried both http/https - same issue

Comment: Is it possible that a firewall rule is preventing these connections ? Do you have a load balancer or CDN ?